# Bash: trying to echo a string if there isn't enough memory left on the server

Tags: bash, memory

I would like my script to echo a string, in case there isn't enough memory left on the server. I have tried many things, but the script does not work, I'm afraid its because of converting a string into a number ?

Here is what I have got:

```
freem=`free -m | sed -n '3p' | tail -c6 | xargs`
max_memory=1000
if [ freem -lt max_memory ]
then echo 'not enough'
else echo 'yay'
fi
```

freem does have the correct value, but the if does not work, it says:

```
check_memory.sh: 3: [: Illegal number: freem
```

I have tried many things, but I cannot get it to work :(.

Could someone please help me ?

Thank you

Comment: You just need to use `$var` instead of `var`. In your case, `if [ $freem -lt $max_memory ]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of fedorqui already shows what you missed (the $'s for the variable names). I'd use something like:

```
let freem=$(free -m | awk '/cache:/ {print $NF}')
let max_memory=1000
if [ $freem -lt $max_memory ]
then echo 'not enough'
else echo 'yay'
fi
```

I prefer using `$( )` instead of back ticks for readability. By using `let` you state that arg is an arithmetic expression, which makes more sense when comparing values.

Comment: ok thank you. but quick question, the let doesn't seem to work inside a bash script (.sh), why is that ? (I just removed it and it seems to work)

Comment: That is weird. On my system bash does not have any problems with the `let`. Which version of bash are you using? (I tried it on bash 3.2.25 and 4.1.2).

Comment: 4.2.45 (latest ubuntu). even though I don't understand that part its ok, it works, thats what matters. Thanks for your help :)